# Combining two variables into a string for Google Scipts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script as part of an onEdit(e) function for a Google Sheets Spreadsheet:

```
//Add annual items to working area
if(col == 12 && row >= 31 && row < 54 && range.isChecked()){
var bill = range.offset(0,-3).getValue();
var dbill = range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
var amt = range.offset(0,1).getValue();
var due = range.offset(0, -1).getValue();

due.setFullYear(due.getFullYear() + 1);
Bu.getRange('P52').setValue(bill);
Bu.getRange('R52').setValue(amt);
range.offset(0,-1).setValue(due+' ('dbill')');
range.uncheck();
BillSort();
}​​
```

I'd like to change it so that bill and dbill are combined into a string like: ***bill* (*dbill*)** and then dropped into cell P52 rather than just **bill**.

My initial thinking was to use the following change:

```
Bu.getRange('P52').setValue(bill+' (' dbill')';​
```

but that didn't work. What is the proper/best method to use these two variable values in a string?

Comment: See the colors here or in your editor. Use  matching close brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bu.getRange('P52').setValue(bill + ' (' + dbill + ')');​
```

or

```
Bu.getRange('P52').setValue(`${bill} (${dbill})`);​
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I do see some issues with my initial thinking, however, both of those give me the same as with my own attempt:

Syntax error: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token line: 63 file: macros.gs

Comment: @RyanDay Check now